# Hibernate time to first action - too slow

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, web

I started a new Java Spring Hibernate project. I only have a few POJO's for now. But hibernate's first actions (drop, create table etc.) happens too late, almost 30 seconds after project gets started.

[image: Hibernate too slow]

As I said, there isn't much of a code right now. I'm very new at Java web development and Hibernate. This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=*****

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.bmt311.dershane.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

Comment: You are assuming those actions "happen too late" but have you considered the roundtrip from the machine the application is running on to the database and back for every DML statement? Also, in "real world" projects almost no one uses "create-drop" but rather either relies on a present database, an installer or a DB migration tool but Hibernate's mechanisms are way too simple for anything more sophisticated.

Comment: I made that assumption based on what I saw on other people's projects - mainly tutorials. Of course it's not a real world project, and I expect some performance drawbacks, but I think "25-30 secs after startup" is a problem. I think I'm doing something very wrong.

Comment: I see that you're using Oracle so are you running it locally or how is your set-up? Depending on the fact that e.g. your database runs on a server and DML needs to be sent over network roundtrip times can be high.

Comment: Yes, my db is Oracle but it is installed on the same computer. So I don't expect any "network roundtrip times".

Comment: add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false` to t he `application.properties`. Also depending on your database preparing a schema can be slow. Another thing, don't use a validation query (JDBC4 has better build in ways of connection validation which the connection pool already uses).

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false worked. Thanks. First action is done immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you always recreate a database when developing locally? Oracle AFAIK does quite a lot of stuff(reserve diskspace etc.) when using DDL so it is generally a bad idea to use create-drop with Oracle. Try using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` instead for developing locally, or even better, use a dedicated tool for schema management like Liquibase or Flyway and use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.

Comment: Agree with this awnser, and would probably use ddl-auto=validate to make sure the database is in sync (more or less).